# Specific string slicing

Tags: python, arrays, string, slice

I have a large string array  which i store as an nparray named np_base: `np.shape(np_base)
Out[32]: (65000000, 1)`

what i intend to do is to vertically slice the array in order to decompose it into multiple columns that i'll store later in an independant way, so i tried to loop over the row indexes and to append:

`for i in range(65000000):
   INCDN.append(np.base[i, 0][0:5])`

but this trhows out a memory error.

Could anybody please help me out with this issue, i've been searching for days for an alternative way to slice the string array.

Thanks,

Comment: A few questions. Are you just looking to extract first 5 characters of each string? Would an in place operation work? Can you  discard the rest of your string? Are there repeated strings so you can factorize?

Comment: Hi, basically each line of my array is stored as a single array, whereas i want to slice the whole array in order to get the column composed of the 5 first character which is an index, then the column composed of the 5 other following characters which is a first feature, then the other following 5 characters and so on .. i guess factorizing is the best solution

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to apply a function to a numpy array one of which is the following:

```
np_truncated = np.vectorize(lambda x: x[:5])(np_base)
```

Your approach with iterativly appending a list is usally the least perfomed solution in most contexts.

---

Alternatively, if you intent to work with many columns, you might want to use `pandas`.

```
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.DataFrame(np_base, columns=["Raw"])
truncated = df.Raw.str.slice(0,5)
```

Comment: Hello, many thanks, i tried the vectorize approach and as i expected, it worked. This was basically the function i was seeking but i'm quite new to Python so i couldn't figure it out.